# comparing date in twig returns only positive numbers

Tags: php, twig

I have tried two different dates compared to 03-26-2020.  03-20-2020 and 04-01-2020

When using the compare

```
{% set cdate = 'now'|date('d-m-Y') %}
{% set fkdate1 = '2020-03-20'|date('d-m-Y') %}
{% set fkdate2 = '2020-04-01'|date('d-m-Y') %}
{{ date(fkdate1).diff(date(cdate)).days }}
{{ date(fkdate2).diff(date(cdate)).days }}
```

Both dates return 6.  It is possible to have it return -6 or +6? ie: is it above or below, otherwise i do not know with it showing 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `invert` property of the [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class

```html
{% set cdate = "NOW" %}
{% set fkdate1 = '2020-03-20'|date('d-m-Y') %}
{% set fkdate2 = '2020-04-02'|date('d-m-Y') %}


{% set diff_one = date(cdate).diff(date(fkdate1)) %}
{% set diff_two = date(cdate).diff(date(fkdate2)) %}


{{ diff_one.invert ? 'minus'}} {{  diff_one.days }} days
{{ diff_two.invert ? 'minus'}} {{  diff_two.days }} days
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ke40sl)